# How to blur the background image of the main layout in android?

Tags: android, alpha

I just want to make the background image to look blur(like defocus),I used alpha but it was not only setting alpha to my background image but also to the whole content...Is there any way that I can set blur effect only to my background image!!!..

need help thanks in advance!!..

Comment: See this page: http://trickyandroid.com/advanced-blurring-techniques/

Comment: why it is down voted??

Answer (score 2):

Please use below tutorial for blur background

1. NavigationDrawer :
   https://github.com/charbgr/BlurNavigationDrawer
2. Fragment:
   https://github.com/tvbarthel/BlurDialogFragment
3. Image : If you want to blur an image in layout :
   https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur
4. Layout: 
   https://github.com/PomepuyN/BlurEffectForAndroidDesign

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ```
   private static final String BLURRED_IMG_PATH = "blurred_image.png";
   private static final int TOP_HEIGHT = 700;
   private ListView mList;
   private ImageView mBlurredImage;
   private View headerView;
   private ImageView mNormalImage;
   private ScrollableImageView mBlurredImageHeader;
   private Switch mSwitch;
   private float alpha;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // Get the screen width
       final int screenWidth = ImageUtils.getScreenWidth(this);

       // Find the view
       mBlurredImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blurred_image);
       mNormalImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.normal_image);
       mBlurredImageHeader = (ScrollableImageView) findViewById(R.id.blurred_image_header);
       mSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.background_switch);
       mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

       // prepare the header ScrollableImageView
       mBlurredImageHeader.setScreenWidth(screenWidth);

       // Action for the switch
       mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               if (isChecked) {
                   mBlurredImage.setAlpha(alpha);
               } else {
                   mBlurredImage.setAlpha(0f);

               }

           }
       });

       // Try to find the blurred image
       final File blurredImage = new File(getFilesDir() + BLURRED_IMG_PATH);
       if (!blurredImage.exists()) {

           // launch the progressbar in ActionBar
           setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

           new Thread(new Runnable() {

               @Override
               public void run() {

                   // No image found => let's generate it!
                   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                   options.inSampleSize = 2;
                   Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image, options);
                   Bitmap newImg = Blur.fastblur(MainActivity.this, image, 12);
                   ImageUtils.storeImage(newImg, blurredImage);
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           updateView(screenWidth);

                           // And finally stop the progressbar
                           setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                       }
                   });

               }
           }).start();

       } else {

           // The image has been found. Let's update the view
           updateView(screenWidth);

       }

       String[] strings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_content);

       // Prepare the header view for our list
       headerView = new View(this);
       headerView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TOP_HEIGHT));
       mList.addHeaderView(headerView);
       mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, strings));
       mList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

           @Override
           public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

           }

           /**
            * Listen to the list scroll. This is where magic happens ;)
            */
           @Override
           public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

               // Calculate the ratio between the scroll amount and the list
               // header weight to determinate the top picture alpha
               alpha = (float) -headerView.getTop() / (float) TOP_HEIGHT;
               // Apply a ceil
               if (alpha > 1) {
                   alpha = 1;
               }

               // Apply on the ImageView if needed
               if (mSwitch.isChecked()) {
                   mBlurredImage.setAlpha(alpha);
               }

               // Parallax effect : we apply half the scroll amount to our
               // three views
               mBlurredImage.setTop(headerView.getTop() / 2);
               mNormalImage.setTop(headerView.getTop() / 2);
               mBlurredImageHeader.handleScroll(headerView.getTop() / 2);

           }
       });
   }

   private void updateView(final int screenWidth) {
       Bitmap bmpBlurred = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getFilesDir() + BLURRED_IMG_PATH);
       bmpBlurred = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpBlurred, screenWidth, (int) (bmpBlurred.getHeight()
               * ((float) screenWidth) / (float) bmpBlurred.getWidth()), false);

       mBlurredImage.setImageBitmap(bmpBlurred);

       mBlurredImageHeader.setoriginalImage(bmpBlurred);
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: my icons and text are in white color.....if i use white image...then all gets invisible....I want to set some grey .effect on image ,so that I can see my icons and text..

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin code, use view effect Library :

1- Add library in build.gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.github.mirrajabi:view-effects:e355a1bac4'
```

2- Blure the background of root view or view, here  Constraint Layout blured by  20%

```
 ViewFilter.getInstance(this)
        .setRenderer(  BlurRenderer(20))
        .applyFilterOnView(  root_constraintLayout,
            root_constraintLayout    )
```

my github repository for blur background : [link](https://github.com/HJaliliani/BlurActivityBackground)